# Correct method to post from ajax to apigility rest-connected module

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, laminas-api-tools

I am using Zend Studio with Apigility, Zend Framework 2.  I have created a user service which works fine.  If I use the Test Service, then I am able to POST to my module and generate a new user.  When trying to post from a page with AJAX, I receive no usable error message to tell me why it is failing and I can view the database and view that the record was not added.  Here is what the function looks like:

```
function addUser() {
    jQuery.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg('Loading');    
    $.ajax({    
        url : gatewayURL + '/users-cc',
        cache : false,
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            'FirstName' : 'FirstTest',      
            'LastName' : 'LastTest',
            'UserName' : 'TestName',
        }),
        success : function(data, status, xhr) {
            jQuery.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            onAddUser(data);        
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            jQuery.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            onAddUser(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

From what I can see from the server, I can tell that the script seems to break before it actually hits the page, since I have an error_log entry that documents when the script is actually run.

The gatewayURL identified is the full connection to my website, which works for retrieving records just fine.  It's just that this post does not seem to connect.  I've tried debugging with chrome tools and the xhr.responseText is empty, so not very useful.

I'm not sure if it's helpful but the Apigility module is set to use ArraySerializable as the hydrator.  If Apigility is throwing an error, it is not being recorded to the log.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.